# Create image-ojbects dynamically from library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, object

I've created an Array with the names of my image-Classes in the library.

```
var myArr:Array = new Array("myPic1","myPic2","myPic3");
```

Normally if I would like to create an object of my class I would

```
var libraryImage:Bitmap;
libraryImage = new Bitmap(new myPic1(0,0));
```

But how can I iterate through the array and create my images dynamically?

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i<myArr.length; i++){
   var libraryImage:Bitmap;
   libraryImage = new Bitmap(new myArr[i](0,0));
}
```

doesn't works

Comment: `new Bitmap(new myPic1(0,0))` You want your bitmapData to have no height nor width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myArr:Array = new Array(new myPic1(0,0), new myPic2(0,0), new myPic3(0,0));
for(var i:uint = 0; i<myArr.length; i++){
    var libraryImage:Bitmap;
    libraryImage = new Bitmap(myArr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i<myArr.length; i++){
  var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(myArr[i]) as Class;
  var libraryImage:Bitmap;
  libraryImage = new Bitmap(new myClass(0,0));
}
```